# How to open port 25 on AWS LightSail Linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-lightsail

I have a Linux box on AWS LightSail. My application (**NOT WordPress**) needs to relay emails out to a smarthost (email security system) on smtp port 25. However,  when I tested this port with telnet, I found that this port is blocked. I know that for example for EC2 instance you can submit a request per use case to lift this restriction, or with WordPress you have plugins or other options. However, cannot find any solution for LightSail Linux instances. I do not want to use AWS SES.

Comment: Can you use port 587 (with TLS) instead of port 25?

Comment: open the port in your firewall setting. [Documentation](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail)

Comment: @Lamanus these are for incoming. and by the way I already have port 25 as a custom port in my firewall setting. If you check EC2 documentation (assuming LightSail is also similar), AWS actually blocks all SMTP traffic to prevent spammers, so this is a global setting that cannot be  changed from these firewall rules. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein 587 is also blocked. I think it applies to all SMTP outbound traffic.

Comment: it restricts the traffic but not blocked as far as i know. You may follow this, [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/?nc1=h_ls)

Comment: @Lamanus that is what I am hoping for. it's been over 24 hours so far since I submitted the request through that page. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Lamanus that's for EC2, not Lightsail.  Lightsail instances are not actually owned by your AWS account (as you can see by querying the instance metadata service, and which is why your Lightsail instances do not appear in your EC2 console) so I would be very surprised if this works.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you may be right as I have not heard anything back yet from AWS. Do you know of any other way? I am coming to the conclusion that with LightSail AWS does not want you to route SMTP traffic outside of their private network unless you use something like WordPress!!

Answer (score 4):

We had this issue, but had problems figuring out where / how to submit this without a support plan. Eventually we received the following instructions from Amazon:

They stated the request could be submitted at the following URL:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/

And to do the following:

1. Sign in with your AWS account root user credentials, and then open the Request to Remove Email Sending Limitations form.
2. In the Use Case Description field, provide a description of your use case.
3. (Optional) Provide the AWS-owned Elastic IP addresses that you use to send outbound email, as well as any reverse DNS records that AWS needs to associate with the Elastic IP addresses. AWS will use this information to help reduce the chance that email sent from the Elastic IP addresses is marked as spam.
4. Choose Submit.

Comment: UGHGHGHGHGHGH, Amazon, UGHGHGHG, spammers!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have the same issue, you can submit a request to AWS support. Amazon only states that this is for EC2 instances, however it does the same thing for LightSail. I managed to resolve my issue this way. It takes up to 48 hours though.